# Login with Google in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, google-signin, laravel-backpack

I have a project that consists of an admin panel (using [backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/)) in Laravel 8.x.
I want to implement login with google in it with the help of [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite). My problem is I don’t have full grasp on how Laravel/Backpack authentification/login works 100% and so I’m unable to implement this.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `config/backpack/base.php`. You'll find configuration options there that will allow you to completely disable the Backpack authentication, so you can use your own routes, controller, PasswordBroker, guard etc.

You're probably interested in [`setup_auth_routes`, under ROUTING](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/config/backpack/base.php#L191-L194), to disable the default auth routes, then in [everything under AUTHENTICATION](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/config/backpack/base.php#L208-L251) to configure your own.

Note that the stock Backpack authentication is just a clone of Laravel's  auth. It uses exactly the same principles, classes etc, it's just that they're under the `backpack` name.